# Select * From tab1, tb2, tb3, etc in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ado.net, linq-to-dataset

I am trying to convert the above statement to LINQ.
I have multiple tables (with an identifier in the first column) and I need to "multiply" them so that I get a table as a result where all possible combinations are shown (e.g. table 1 = 2 rows, table 2 = 2 rows, table 3 = 2 rows, resulting table 2*2*2 = 8 rows).

If I have a sqlite db I used to do it in this way:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM tab1,tab2,tab3;
SQLDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con);
adapter.Fill(ds.Tables[1]);
```

Now the db is not longer a sqlite db but a dataset. This dataset contains the tab1,tab2,tab3 etc. Now I would like to do the same as before - multiply the tables. How can this be done with a dataset (by using LINQ if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

In a LINQ query expression you just need multiple `from` clauses, e.g.

```
var query = from row1 in tab1
            from row2 in tab2
            from row3 in tab3
            select new { row1, row2, row3 };
```

If you don't want to use query expressions, you'd use `SelectMany` instead, but in this case a query expression is going to be simpler.

For datasets, you'd probably want something like:

```
var query = from row1 in ds.Tables["tab1"].AsEnumerable()
            from row2 in ds.Tables["tab2"].AsEnumerable()
            from row3 in ds.Tables["tab3"].AsEnumerable()
            select new { row1, row2, row3 };
```

Make sure you have a `using` directive for `System.Data` so that you can pull in [`DataTableExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions) for `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer! This is more or less how I have already done it. Unfortunately I can´t handle the result ;-). The result (query) should be added to my existing dataset as a new table but I am not having a clue how to do that.

Comment: @derchrome: Well presumably you need to create a table with all the columns you want, and create new rows with those values. Unfortunately you haven't asked about any of that in this question. I suggest you leave this question as it was before (rolling back your edit that basically asks what you're *really* interested in as an afterthought) and ask a *new* question which explains what problems you're running into when creating a new table. Note that where you get the data from for that new table is pretty irrelevant - it could just be a list...

Comment: Thanks Jon. I tried a little bit by myself in the meantime and found a solution for it. Maybe it is not the best one but it works :-) I put the result into a list and within this list I add the different rows to one big row

Comment: Any idea how to convert it to a dynamic linq expression? If I don´t know the numbers of tables while programming.

Comment: @derchrome: Again, that's a different question to the one you asked - so you should ask a new question, with more information.